# Copy to clipboard function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create a form with multiple fields with Copy to Clipboard function.
This is for intranet in my company and it will work on older version of IE.
I have the code for one form element. I want to have multiple form elements.

My code example:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyToClipboard () {
            var input = document.getElementById ("toClipboard");
            window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", input.value);
        }
        function ShowClipboardContent () {
            alert (window.clipboardData.getData ("Text"));
        }
        function ClearClipboard () {
            window.clipboardData.clearData ("Text");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="toClipboard" value="text to clipboard"/>
    <button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy text to clipboard</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick='ShowClipboardContent ();'>Show text data in clipboard</button>
    <button onclick='ClearClipboard ();'>Clear text data from clipboard</button>
</body>
```

What I want is to have multiple fields, for example:
 - text field 1
 - text field 2
 - text field 3

Below that would be a copy to clipboard button. I don't have required knowledge to do with multiple form elements so any help would be appreciated :)

And also if there is a way when my text is copied co clipboard it would be shown like this (with some lines ----):

---

|Text field 1 | Text entered in form field

---

|Text field 2 | Text inserted in clipboard area

---

|Text field 3 | Text inserted in clipboard area

---

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it correct that you are using jQuery?

Comment: If your code works for a single element, just pass the id of the element as a argument of your function, eg: CopyToClipboard('toClipboard'); and then, from within your function:  document.getElementById(arguments[0]);